# Call a method of Object type in array, not array type

Tags: c#, arrays, object, derived-class

I have a parent class, account, with two derived, `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingsAccount`. Those child classes have their own variants of the methods. I want to call the method of the object which is store in the array. So the array of type `Account` holds objects of type `SavingsAccount` and `CheckingsAccount`.

I thought I could call it by doing the `Account[0].CalculateInterest`

`CalculateInterest` in a method inside `SavingsAccount`.

[image: This error is thrown]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomersPartTwo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Account[] customerAccounts = new Account[4];
            decimal temp = 0;

            customerAccounts[0] = new SavingsAccount(25, 0.03m);
            customerAccounts[1] = new SavingsAccount(200, 0.015m);
            customerAccounts[2] = new CheckingAccount(80, 1);
            customerAccounts[3] = new CheckingAccount(400, 0.5m);


            Console.WriteLine("Account 1 balance: " + customerAccounts[0].Balance.ToString("C"));

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");
            temp = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            customerAccounts[0].Debit(temp);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to deposit: ");
            temp = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            customerAccounts[0].Credit(temp);

            if (customerAccounts[0].GetType() == typeof(SavingsAccount))
            {
                customerAccounts[0].Credit(SavingsAccount.CalculateInterest());
            }

        }


        /* Base Class ------------------------------------*/
        class Account
        {
            private decimal balance;

            /* Property */
            public decimal Balance
            {
                get { return balance; }
                set
                {
                    if (value < 0)
                        balance = 0;
                    else
                        balance = value;
                }
            }

            /* Constructor */
            public Account(decimal initialBalance)
            {
                Balance = initialBalance;
            }

            /* Method to add to balance */
            public void Credit(decimal addedFunds)
            {
                Balance += addedFunds;
            }

            /* Method to subtract from balance */
            public void Debit(decimal subtractedFunds)
            {
                if (subtractedFunds > Balance)
                    Console.WriteLine("Debit amount exceeds balance amount");
                else
                    Balance -= subtractedFunds;
            }
        }
        /* Base Class ------------------------------------*/


        class SavingsAccount : Account
        {
            private decimal interestRate;

            /* Constructor */
            public SavingsAccount(decimal initialBalance, decimal rateOfInterest) : base(initialBalance)
            {
                interestRate = rateOfInterest;
            }

            /* Method to calculate interest */
            public decimal CalculateInterest()
            {
                decimal earnedInterest = 0;

                earnedInterest = Balance * interestRate;

                return earnedInterest;
            }
        }


        class CheckingAccount : Account
        {
            private decimal transactionFee;

            /* Constructor */
            public CheckingAccount(decimal initialBalance, decimal usageFee) : base(initialBalance)
            {
                transactionFee = usageFee;
            }

            /* Method to add to balance */
            public new void Credit(decimal addedFunds)
            {
                Balance += addedFunds;
                Balance -= transactionFee;
            }

            /* Method to subtract from balance */
            public new void Debit(decimal subtractedFunds)
            {
                if (subtractedFunds > Balance)
                    Console.WriteLine("Debit amount exceeds balance amount");
                else
                    Balance -= (subtractedFunds + transactionFee);              
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to invoke `CalculateInterest` on an instance of `Account`, e.g `customerAccounts[0].Credit(customerAccounts[0].CalculateInterest())`. Can you show us your `Account` class as well? Does `CalculateInterest` exist on this class also? If not, you may need to cast your instance to `SavingsAccount`.

Comment: You also might consider if there really is a difference between a checking account and a savings account, other than rules-based (property-based) differences (like minimum balance, maximum withdrawl, maintenance fees, etc.), which can be specified as properties on an instance. If this is the case, then it might make sense to just have a `BankAccount` class, and then create instances of that, like `BankAccount checkingAccount = new BankAccount();` This way your method only needs to worry about a single type.

Comment: @Jeppe    I tried this: if (customerAccounts[x].GetType() == typeof(SavingsAccount))
                {
                    temp = customerAccounts[x].CalculateInterest();
                    customerAccounts[x].Credit(temp);
                }

Still not working. It seems like it's not acknowledging the data type of the object inside the array, or something. Getting a "does not contain definition" error.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try in this way?

```
if (customerAccounts[0] is SavingAccount sa)
{
    customerAccounts[0].Credit(sa.CalculateInterest());
}
```